Playwright y Python hacer click en elementos class React
Buenos días a toda la comunidad de este gran sitio,
Tengo un problema a tratar de definir o encontrar un elemento u objeto al cual debo hacer click para avanzar con la automatización de la prueba.
El sitio esta desarrollado en Python y usa la biblioteca React como plantilla de cada página.
Usando el terminal de VSCode he tratado de localizar de muchas formas posible a cada objeto al cual debo hacer click para avanzar con la automatización de la prueba.
Tengo estos objetos que más que definidos son, al parecer, modelados por el gestor, por ejemplo:
<svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true" style="cursor: pointer;">

He probado usando:
page.wait_for_selector('[svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root"]').focus()
page.click('[svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root"]')

hrefElement = page.get_by_text('class=MuiSvgIcon-root')
hrefElement.click()

Dentro de algunos de los ya varios comandos en busca de definir el elemento para darle click.
De antemano muchas gracias por vuestra valiosa ayuda.
